# How to access fields from node template without render

Tags: 7, theming

within node template, i am trying to print a content type field value. usually I see the render function used to print the field value in the template e.g. `render($content['field_name']).` how do i just print the field value?

`$content['field_name'][$lang][0]['value']` doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$lang = field_language('node', $node, 'field_name'); // gets field language

print $node->field_name[$lang][0]['value']; // prints field
```